# Why won't Postgres filter my date range partitions?

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning

I have a table that uses [declarative partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html) (w00t!) to partition tables by date range - one year in my case.

When I query against the table - `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE date > date '2016-01-01'`, it works exactly as intended; only tables containing newer data are scanned.

When I specify a date using variables or functions (`CURRENT_DATE`, `NOW()`, etc), `EXPLAIN` says it scans every partition.

Things that work as intended:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE date > date '2016-01-01'
--
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE date > '2016-01-01'::date
```

Things that scan all partitions unnecessarily:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE date > CURRENT_DATE
--
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE date > NOW()
--
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE date > (NOW() - 365)::date
--
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE date > (SELECT (NOW()::date - 365)::date AS d)
-- Even CTEs are no dice:
WITH a AS (SELECT CURRENT_DATE AS d)
SELECT * FROM tbl, a WHERE date > a.d
-- Same with JOINs
SELECT w.*
FROM (CURRENT_DATE - 365 as d) a
LEFT JOIN wtf w ON w.date > a.d
```

..etc

I get the same behavior with other comparison operators - `=`, `<`, etc.

The docs say I don't need an idx on the field (which I don't anyways). I added one just in case and it did not help.

Why is this happening, and what can I do to stop it (preferably without adding complication to a simple query)?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes) and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: That's because planner doesn't know output of now() till executing.

Comment: Thanks @JustMe -  would you post this as an answer so I can accept it and remove the unnecessary SQL and output of EXPLAIN so this can help other people as well?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to JustMe for answering this- see the comments on the OP.

The issue lies with when `NOW()` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` are evaluated in relation to `FROM`; it's the same issue you see when you try to filter in a join ala `WHERE join_table.a > from_table.b`.

Supposing today is Jan 1, 1970, these queries

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_stuff WHERE date > NOW()::date;
--
SELECT * FROM my_stuff WHERE date > '1970-01-01'::date;
```

will necessarily produce an identical resultset but will not necessarily be evaluated in an identical way.

That's why this is happening and unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a simple way to stop it. A function seems to be the best-ish option:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc()
    RETURNS setof tbl
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $$
DECLARE
    n date := CURRENT_DATE - 365;
BEGIN
    RETURN query EXECUTE $a$
        SELECT * FROM tbl
        WHERE date > $1;
    $a$ using n;
END $$;
```

You can test this by changing `RETURNS setof tbl` to `RETURNS setof text` and `SELECT...` to `EXPLAIN SELECT...`